# Windows Server 2012 VBScript gets permission denied deleting files

Tags: vbscript, permission-denied, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a folder on my server (Windows Server 2012 r2) that is shared with Everyone. All my users upload a plain text inventory file each day. I then have a vbscript that I scheduled to run under my Administrator credentials which deletes these files after reading them. However, I get permission denied errors when trying to delete or move the files.

Here is some simple code that fails:

```
Dim PathtoInventoryFiles
Dim myFSO
Dim myFile
Dim colFiles

PathtoInventoryFiles = "D:\Inventory$"
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFiles = myFSO.GetFolder(PathtoInventoryFiles).Files

For Each myFile In colFiles
    wscript.echo myFile.path
    'Tried both of the following (only one at a time of course)
    myFSO.DeleteFile myFile.Path 'Permission denied
    myFile.Delete 'Permission denied
Next

Set myFSO = Nothing
Set colFiles = Nothing
```

The echo produces a correct path to a good and existing file. So I'm thinking I have a permissions issue? This is a pretty plain vanilla installation of Server 2012.

Comment: Are you able to delete the files via Explorer, using the same account?

Comment: Yes I can. I turned UAC off, and I verified that the Administrators group owns the files and folders. I even gave Full Control to Everyone. I think I set it so my neighbor's girlfriend's dog's one night hook up could delete the file. But apparently my vbscript is a little more restricted.

Comment: Try _creating_ a file as Admin in the folder (via Explorer) and then see if your script will delete it.

Comment: Check if the file(s) are opened (`net file` for remote connections, [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) for local processes).

Comment: You da man Ansgar!! Rebooting "fixed" the issue so I started investigating that. It turns out the files were being left open in a different process. So, as usual, it was just me being stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a "permission denied" error on a file where the permissions already allow access usually means that the file is (still) opened by someone/something. You can check that with `net file` for remote connections, or [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) for local processes.