# Run Time Error 70 Permission Denied Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have created some code that will move emails to a folder, add a unique ID, put into a spreadsheet and not overwrite duplicates.

This worked when I made it and now it comes up with Run Time Error 70 Permission Denied. Been looking through the code and cant figure out where or why this is happening.

Can you guys see anything I am missing?

```
Option Explicit
Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\Emails" 'The path to save the messages

Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim olItem As Object
    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With xlSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
        '.Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
        CreateFolders fPath
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
        For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
            NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If olItem.Class = 43 Then
                .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Sender
                .Cells(NextRow, 2) = olItem.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, 3) = olItem.SentOn
                '.Cells(NextRow, 4) =
                .Cells(NextRow, 5) = SaveMessage(olItem)
                .Cells(NextRow, 6) = olItem.Body
            End If
        Next olItem
    End With
     MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
lbl_Exit:
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function SaveMessage(olItem As Object) As String
Dim Fname As String
    Fname = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & Chr(32) & _
            Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "HH.MM") & Chr(32) & olItem.SenderName & " - " & olItem.Subject
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveMessage = SaveUnique(olItem, fPath, Fname)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object, _
                            strPath As String, _
                            strFileName As String) As String
Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
    SaveUnique = strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Sub CreateFolders(strPath As String)
Dim strTempPath As String
Dim iPath As Long
Dim vPath As Variant
    vPath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = vPath(0) & "\"
    For iPath = 1 To UBound(vPath)
        strPath = strPath & vPath(iPath) & "\"
        If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then MkDir strPath
    Next iPath
End Sub

Private Function FolderExists(ByVal PathName As String) As Boolean
   Dim nAttr As Long
   On Error GoTo NoFolder
   nAttr = GetAttr(PathName)
   If (nAttr And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
      FolderExists = True
   End If
NoFolder:
End Function

Private Function FileExists(filespec) As Boolean
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filespec) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Can you find the offending line if you work through it line by line with `F8`?

Comment: My god.... I found the issue. The folder where I was trying to save the emails had special permissions..... (sorry). Now resolved.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Add an answer to your own question instead of adding a comment. :)

Comment: Thanks Tim..... My head really hurts today. Cant believe I missed that haha.

Comment: Tim If I have a diffrent question on the code above can I raise a new question using the same code?

Comment: Been [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297449/windows-server-2012-vbscript-gets-permission-denied-deleting-files) myself

Comment: I'm not a mod or anything, but I don't see why you can't create a second question.

Comment: Cool I have fired my second [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036165/how-can-i-stop-re-imports-of-emails-and-create-hyperlink) question up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now resolved. It was due to the folder the emails saving to having special permissions.

Comment: I have to wait another 15 hours to do that.